# direct access to Objective-C's isa is Deprecated in favor of object_getClass()

Tags: xcode, class, instruction-set

Here is my Code I want to change:

```
       if(JK_EXPECT_T(object->isa == encodeState->fastClassLookup.stringClass))     { isClass = JKClassString;     }
  else if(JK_EXPECT_T(object->isa == encodeState->fastClassLookup.numberClass))     { isClass = JKClassNumber;     }
  else if(JK_EXPECT_T(object->isa == encodeState->fastClassLookup.dictionaryClass)) { isClass = JKClassDictionary; }
  else if(JK_EXPECT_T(object->isa == encodeState->fastClassLookup.arrayClass))      { isClass = JKClassArray;      }
  else if(JK_EXPECT_T(object->isa == encodeState->fastClassLookup.nullClass))       { isClass = JKClassNull;       }
  else {
  slowClassLookup:
         if(JK_EXPECT_T([object isKindOfClass:[NSString     class]])) { if(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug == NO) { encodeState->fastClassLookup.stringClass     = object->isa; } isClass = JKClassString;     }
    else if(JK_EXPECT_T([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber     class]])) { if(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug == NO) { encodeState->fastClassLookup.numberClass     = object->isa; } isClass = JKClassNumber;     }
    else if(JK_EXPECT_T([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])) { if(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug == NO) { encodeState->fastClassLookup.dictionaryClass = object->isa; } isClass = JKClassDictionary; }
    else if(JK_EXPECT_T([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray      class]])) { if(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug == NO) { encodeState->fastClassLookup.arrayClass      = object->isa; } isClass = JKClassArray;      }
    else if(JK_EXPECT_T([object isKindOfClass:[NSNull       class]])) { if(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug == NO) { encodeState->fastClassLookup.nullClass       = object->isa; } isClass = JKClassNull;       }
            if(JK_EXPECT_F((keyObject->isa      != encodeState->fastClassLookup.stringClass)) && JK_EXPECT_F(([keyObject   isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] == NO))) { jk_encode_error(encodeState, @"Key must be a string object."); return(1); }
```

How should I go about changing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace

```
object->isa
```

with

```
object_getClass(object)
```

Comment: Ok thanks. This is what I thought. I was just checking this was the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 if(JK_EXPECT_T(object_getClass(object) == encodeState->fastClassLookup.stringClass))     { isClass = JKClassString;     }
  else if(JK_EXPECT_T(object_getClass(object) == encodeState->fastClassLookup.numberClass))     { isClass = JKClassNumber;     }
  else if(JK_EXPECT_T(object_getClass(object) == encodeState->fastClassLookup.dictionaryClass)) { isClass = JKClassDictionary; }
  else if(JK_EXPECT_T(object_getClass(object) == encodeState->fastClassLookup.arrayClass))      { isClass = JKClassArray;      }
  else if(JK_EXPECT_T(object_getClass(object) == encodeState->fastClassLookup.nullClass))       { isClass = JKClassNull;       }
  else {
  slowClassLookup:
         if(JK_EXPECT_T([object isKindOfClass:[NSString     class]])) { if(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug == NO) { encodeState->fastClassLookup.stringClass     = object_getClass(object); } isClass = JKClassString;     }
    else if(JK_EXPECT_T([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber     class]])) { if(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug == NO) { encodeState->fastClassLookup.numberClass     = object_getClass(object); } isClass = JKClassNumber;     }
    else if(JK_EXPECT_T([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])) { if(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug == NO) { encodeState->fastClassLookup.dictionaryClass = object_getClass(object); } isClass = JKClassDictionary; }
    else if(JK_EXPECT_T([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray      class]])) { if(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug == NO) { encodeState->fastClassLookup.arrayClass      = object_getClass(object); } isClass = JKClassArray;      }
    else if(JK_EXPECT_T([object isKindOfClass:[NSNull       class]])) { if(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug == NO) { encodeState->fastClassLookup.nullClass       = object_getClass(object); } isClass = JKClassNull;       }
```

Here is a link for [JSONKitWithoutXcode4Warnings](https://github.com/IgorFedorchuk/JSONKitWithoutXcode4Warnings)

Comment: lol I also created my own github JSONKit version too! https://github.com/jaboston/ios7-jsonkit I guess your project name is more appropriate though hehe :P